# Should I use an API or direct database access?

Tags: sql, api, architecture

I have a database with all my employee's information. Should I build an API or should I give direct access to the database?

The API could be built with Node.js and be a REST API. The database access could be given with different database users / different permission sets.

I'm confused because when I query an API, I usually get JSON data back which is awesome. So I wonder if only I can build an API that contains all the data I want and when I query it, I can have my employee's info back in JSON format.

Comment: I've heavily edited your question. Please feel free to revert if it doesn't reflect your original question. If you do revert, please add some clarification. Comparing an API with a database doesn't make sense: One is an interface, the other one is a way to store data. They are not the same. You need both. The database naturally comes with a way to access it, so I guessed your question was if this way could be used directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are reasons to use a REST API. For example you'll have a app, that will be available to the public, you might don't want to write your SQL queries directly in your code, as well as the credentials to connect to your server. Anyone with the knowledge could decompile your app and see your code and have access to the credentials to you database server. The good approach here is to write an REST API to handle the flow of data between your app and database, since REST API should be designed to be accessed publicly, you'll only have to pass in the data, or just call the api you need, you don't need the servers credentials to connect. If you are going local, then you could use the database approach of yours. Since your app will be used only by your clients.

Comment: So I need a database, but do I really need an API at this point? I can access the database using SQL and my db will be hosted on a server. I do not want anyone access that db except for myself.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, you could use the `REST` approach if you want to, but as I have said above, if your application is only distributed in the company, in which assumed that all of your users is trusted, then you can just use your database approach since your app is not publicly distributed by some other users. Read the reason above, I have stated the reason when to use `REST`.

Comment: I sure do not want my db to be made public but my question is, bear with me, can I still have json data if I use SQL to query my db or is there any other language can return json when the db is queried.

Comment: Yes, `json` is just a data structure, most language supports `json` format to encode/decode your data.